# Time-invariance of a MIMO system

Tags: control-theory

According to my book, given a MIMO system with n inputs and m outputs (corresponding to the n inputs), the model itself is said to be time-invariant if a time shifting of inputs causes a time shifting of outputs. Anyway I am not sure if each output is a function of only one input or not because of "corresponding to the n inputs".

Comment: You previously also posted this question [here](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/40060) and an answer was given to it. Could you comment on that in case it doesn't answer your question or if something isn't clear, before cross posting the same question to other SE sites?

Answer (score 1):

A system is (regardless of the amount of inputs / outputs) time-invariant if applying the same input to the same initial state at time $t$ yields the same response if it is applied at time $t+\tau$. This means that if I push a cart right now, its response should be the same as if I push this cart an hour from now, and the same a day from now and so on. Nothing changes if the same input is applied at a different time, as such its a time-invariant system. an example of a time-variant system could be a leaf spring that looses tension over time due to wear and corrosion. As the response at time $t=0$ (when it has just been made) and $t = \tau$ (a large time of doing nothing) alters.

Comment: This doesn't help me. I would like to study the mathematical model of a generic MIMO system to verify that each output depends on severa inputs.

Comment: @AngeloGiannuzzi You mean that you want to check if a specific system output is influenced by different inputs? This has nothing to do with time invariance.